# Появлении кнопки подробнее при превышении количества символов

Tags: jquery, редактор-текста

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно вывести кнопку подробнее, что бы она появлялась тогда, когда количество символов в тексте превышает 150. По клику на кнопку, текст раскрывался далее...

Comment: В чём у вам возникли сложности?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/string#усечение-строки

Answer (score 0):

Собственно проблему решил немного иначе.
накидал скрипт по проверке высоты блока.. Тоже решение подошло.

```
    <script>
        if($('.contproduct').height() > 50){
        $('.contproduct').height(50);
        $('.open').addClass('visible');
    }

    $('.open').click(function () {
        $('.contproduct').addClass('full');
        $('.open').removeClass('visible');
        $('.close').removeClass('hide');
    });
  $('.close').click(function () {
        $('.contproduct').removeClass('full');
        $('.open').addClass('visible');
        $('.close').addClass('hide');
    });

});
</script>
```